# How can I pass the selected items from spinner and checkbox to another activity?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-spinner, android-checkbox

I need to display the selection that I have chosen from spinner and checkbox from one activity to another activity,however I have completed for editText.I have also set the spinner and values for the spinner in arraylist,  i have no idea of how to proceed further for spinner and also I don't know how to use checkbox.I need to pass the spinner and checkbox selected values from MainActivity to secondActivity and I need to display the results as a simple textview in secondActivity as follows:

I need to get my final results something  like this:

Name: Da1

Email: xxxxxxx@gmail.com

Number: 0123456789

Degree: BE or ME(whatever I am choosing)

Place: Australia

Please help me friends. Many thanks in advance. Herewith I have enclosed my modified  coding. But still I am getting values for both Degree and place as null.But I need my result as like the one I specified above.Please let me know the corrections.

MainActivity.java:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        AdapterView . OnItemSelectedListener {

    EditText Name,Email,Number;
    Button submit;
    String [] countryNames ={ "India" ,"Australia" ,"Pakistan" ,"Afghanistan" ,"US","Canada","Israel" };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super . onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R . layout . activity_main );
        Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        Email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        Number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number);
        submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        final Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.simplespinner);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        final CheckBox BEBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.BEBox);


        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = Name.getText().toString();
                String email = Email.getText().toString();
                String number = Number.getText().toString();
                String spinText = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Name",name);
                intent.putExtra("Email",email);
                intent.putExtra("Number",number);
                intent.putExtra("spin",spinText);
                String checkboxString = null;
                if (BEBox.isChecked()) checkboxString = (String) BEBox.getText();
                intent.putExtra("checkbox",checkboxString);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });




        ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter ( this , android . R . layout . simple_spinner_item , countryNames );
        aa . setDropDownViewResource ( android . R . layout . simple_spinner_dropdown_item );

        spin . setAdapter ( aa );
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected ( AdapterView <?> arg0 , View arg1 , int position , long id ) {
        Toast . makeText ( getApplicationContext (), countryNames [ position ], Toast . LENGTH_LONG ). show ();
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected ( AdapterView <?> arg0 ) {

    }
}
```

SecondActivity.java:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    String Name;
    String Email;
    String Number;
    String Degree;
    String Place;


    TextView result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
        Name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Name");
        Email = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Email");
        Number = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Number");
        Degree = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Degree");
        Place = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Place");
        result.setText("Name:"+" "+Name+'\n'+"Email:"+" "+Email+'\n'+"Number:"+" "+Number+'\n'+"Degree:"+" "+Degree+'\n'+"Place:"+" "+Place);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.simplespinner);
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
CheckBox box = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String spinText = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("spin",spinText);

        String checkboxString = null;
        if (box.isChecked()) checkboxString = box.getText();
        intent.putExtra("checkbox",checkboxString);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

If you have a bunch of checkBoxes then you'll have to come up with a better design of getting the values. Maybe you want a `RadioButton` instead of a `CheckBox`?

Comment: I have re-posted my code ...But now I am getting the values for both place and degree as null. Please let me know what should I do?